# Integrating$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\theta^2}{n} \left(\frac{1}{2}e^{-\frac{\theta}{2}} \right) d\theta$

Tags: calculus

So this might be really easy but somehow I can't figure it out.  I have this integral

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\theta^2}{n} \left(\frac{1}{2}e^{-\frac{\theta}{2}} \right) d\theta$$

This is what I did so far:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\theta^2}{2n} e^{-\frac{\theta}{2}}  d\theta$$

Here I did a $u$ sub:

$$ u = \frac{\theta}{2}$$
$$ du = \frac{1}{2} d\theta$$

So the integral becomes

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{4u^2}{n} e^{-u}  du$$
$$\frac{4}{n} \int_{0}^{\infty} u^2 e^{-u}  du$$

Integration by parts perhaps?

Can anyone help me finish the problem?

Comment: Integration by parts twice will do it, step down the exponent of u twice in your substitutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$I= \frac{4}{n} \int_{0}^{\infty} u^2 e^{-u}  du.$$
Note that $$\int_{0}^{\infty} u^2 e^{-u}  du=2$$  by the Laplace transform, so $I=\frac{8}{n}$.  We could apply it directly:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\theta^2}{n} \left(\frac{1}{2}e^{-\frac{\theta}{2}} \right) d\theta=\frac{1}{2n}\frac{2}{(1/2)^3}=\frac{8}{n}.$$

Comment: Ah so you can use Laplace transform or integration by parts twice! Nice!

Comment: yes it is happy new year

Comment: Happy new year to you to sir!